# How to set order by descending in Linq query based on aggregated column?

Tags: c#, linq

Below query has 4 columns, out of 4 columns .. i need only 2 columns which are Vegetables, Pricing.. and also .. Pricing has to be order by descending..

How to include order by for the aggregation value in Linq query?

```
DataTable Dt2 = new DataTable();
            Dt2 = dt.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(r => r.Field<string>("Vegetables"))
                .Select(g =>
                {
                    var row = dt.NewRow();
                    row["Vegetables"] = g.Key;
                    row["Pricing"] = g.Average(r => ParseInt32(r.Field<string>("Pricing")));
                    return row;
                }).CopyToDataTable();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two Linq ways come to mind.

The first is using `.OrderBy<T>()` followed by `.Reverse<T>()`:

```cs
            DataTable Dt2 = new DataTable();
            Dt2 = dt.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(r => r.Field<string>("Vegetables"))
                .Select(g =>
                {
                    var row = dt.NewRow();
                    row["Vegetables"] = g.Key;
                    row["Pricing"] = g.Average(r => Int32.Parse(r.Field<string>("Pricing")));
                    return row;
                })
                .OrderBy(row => row["Pricing"])
                .Reverse()
                .CopyToDataTable();
```

The second is just using `.OrderByDescending<T>()`:

```cs
            DataTable Dt2 = new DataTable();
            Dt2 = dt.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(r => r.Field<string>("Vegetables"))
                .Select(g =>
                {
                    var row = dt.NewRow();
                    row["Vegetables"] = g.Key;
                    row["Pricing"] = g.Average(r => Int32.Parse(r.Field<string>("Pricing")));
                    return row;
                })
                .OrderByDescending(row => row["Pricing"])
                .CopyToDataTable();
```

If you're looking for a non-Linq solution could also apply a sorted `DataView` on the `DataTable` to achieve a similar result.

Comment: Thank you.. I used orderbydescending syntax.. i was aware of reverse syntax .. but didnt know.. how to apply.. thanks for teaching .. great to learn from always learning ..

Comment: In my test syntax , i am getting an error..    just thought of checking with you..    var results = from r in Dt2.DataSet.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()                              
                              .Select (r => new
                              {
                                  ProductName = r.Field<string>("vegetables"),
                                  Description = r.Field<int>("pricing")
                              });

Comment: @goofyui My first thought would be a Pricing value containing something other than digits, such as decimal points or letters, or maybe even null/blank. You should post a new Question with a code sample and the error message(s) you're getting. I'll keep an eye out for it.

Comment: "AlwaysLearning" : Thank you.. But i realized from your point .. able to fix.. it .., It has to be string .. which further parse to Int .. ParseInt32 .. thanks for your help .. Syntax which i copied from you : Int32.Parse(r.Field<string>("Pricing")